# Acessar galeria de fotos pra fazer uploads de fotos pelo inappbrowser

Tags: jquery-mobile

Pessoal tenho um app de noticias, fiz uma parceria com um site de classificados e coloquei um botão no app que direciona pro classificados usando o inappbrowser, no entanto quando o usuário do app esta dentro do site mais precisamente na aba de colocar um produto, ele precisa postar uma foto do produto, o problema que quando o usuário clica no botão imagem não acontece nada, não abre a janela pra escolher a foto... testando com o navegador nativo do do android sem usar o app, funciona normalmente o botão imagem do site da ate a opção de tirar foto, ja usando o app, nao acontece nada... eu acredito que seja permissão mas nao sei como resolver... eu estou usando o dreanweaver para escrever os codigos (jquery-mobile) e depois compilo com o phonegap build CLI 6.3.0, uso os plugin inappbrowser pra navega no site e whitelist plugin pra liberar os acessos Http. alguem pode me dar uma luz... agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver. é só usar o codigo pra abrir o navegador nativo do dispositivo, ao inves de usar o webview.